# How does $P:\Bbb R\rightarrow \{a,b,c\}$induce a quotient topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $p$ be a map of the real line onto the three point set $A=\{a,b,c\}$ .

The map $P:X \rightarrow \{a,b,c\}$ defined by

$$p(x)=\begin{cases}
a,&\text{if }x>0\\
b,&\text{if }x<0\\
c,&\text{if }x=0
\end{cases}$$

induces a quotient topology on $A$.

How does this induce a quotient topology?

I believe I am supposed to first prove that the map $p$ is a quotient map but I don't know how to go about it. Could you please help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition the quotient topology on $A$ induced by $p$ is the topology $\tau$ such that for any $U\subseteq A$, $U\in\tau$ if and only if $p^{-1}[U]$ is open in $\Bbb R$. There are only $8$ subsets of $A$, so you can easily find their inverse images under $p$ and see which have open inverse images. Then just check whether they form a topology on $A$.

In other words, you don’t start by proving that $p$ is a quotient map. If $p$ is to be a quotient map, we know exactly which subsets of $A$ should be open, and we just have to check that they really do form a topology on $A$. While you’re checking, try to see why you will always get a topology in this way.

Comment: You don't really need to check that it's a topology, do you? Any $\tau$ formed in such a way is always a topology.

Comment: @arkeet: Provided that the fibres of $p$ partition the domain, yes, and that is the case here. However, the OP is probably just starting to learn about quotient maps, so I think that checking that we get a topology would be instructive.

Comment: How would they not partition the domain? Preimages preserve intersections. I agree that it would be instructive to list the elements of $\tau$ and check that it is indeed a topology.

Comment: @arkeet: If it turned out that $p$ was defined on a proper subset of the original space (here $\Bbb R$).

Comment: I think it's fair to assume that from the notation $p \colon \mathbb{R} \to \{a,b,c\}$.

Comment: @arkeet: So do I, certainly in this context. There are some contexts in which partial functions might arise, and I’ve seen this notation abused in that way on very rare occasions, but that’s really pretty much out of the question here. I wasn’t thinking so much of that possibility as I was of the possibility that the definition of the function was defective. *That* I definitely *have* seen!

Comment: Thank you Brian, I took the inverse images of all the elements of the power set of $ \{a,b,c\}$ and picked out all those elements whose inverse images are open sets in $\R$.  I ended up with the collection. $\{A,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$  which is a topology on A.

Comment: @J.Kyei: Almost: you're missing $\varnothing$, but you have all of the non-empty open sets.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, you are right. I should include $\phi$ in there.